# Boyer Moore string matching

Tags: algorithms

If I had the pattern = abc and the string: aabcbcbabcabcabc.

Using the Boyer Moore algorithm in order to do string comparison, would you shift by one to the right if you get one match. I'll show my working so far:

```
aabcbcbabcabcabc
abc
```

1) so c doesn't match 
2) b doesn't match 
3) but a matches (would we shift one down here) so your next comparison would be:

```
aabcbcbabcabcabc
 abc
```

4) Then we have c matching 
5) b matches 
6) a matches

Coming to a total of just 6 matches in order to get find the pattern in the string.

Comment: For this particular example, Boyer-Moore is not substantially different from naive string search.

Comment: so it would take 6 matches in total ?

Comment: @amd how would I do it if it was the string "abababababababab" ?

Comment: I think you can work that you for yourself. All of the characters in the pattern are unique, so the “Good Suffix Rule” never comes into play. The character 'c' appears nowhere in the string, so you’ll only have one comparison per alignment.

Comment: @amd I managed to solve it thanks :)